# converting photoshop text layer to html links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, photoshop

Hi i have a photoshop image (.psd) containing over 300 titles in text layers. Many of them are placed tilted and in unusual positions. I need that layout for a website and all the titles must be links or any other clickable object, BUT need to have the same positions as in the .psd. Are there any smart / right way to do this?
I'm familiar with html5, javascript, jquery and angular.js1. I think i would be able to do it manually but there must be a way to automate it (or some of it)? Thanks

Comment: Yea, use text and css transforms to recreate the same output but without psd...

Comment: You can extract the texts and position with Photoshop script.